# Secure login from ASP.NET 3.5/4.0 page to SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, vb.net

What is the most secure way to create an ASP.NET 3.5/4.0 login page connection to an SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb) when logging in with database credentials.

Answer (score -1):

save your database connection string information in the local `machine.config` file.  So on your server under

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.xxx\config\maching.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.xxx\config\maching.config (x64) O/S only)
```

either that or store the connection string in the web.config file.

here's a SO question that asked which was more secure.

[Storing connection strings in machine.config vs storing them in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184187/storing-connection-strings-in-machine-config-vs-storing-them-in-web-config)

Comment: why the heck should you add database connection string to machine.config. there is no part in his message that says something like "for every webapp on one server".... Consider adding something like a connection string to machine.config as bad practice.