# What is the performance impact when placing connection strings in machine.config instead of web/app.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a performance hit when placing your DB connection strings in the machine.config instead of in your application's web.config or app.config?

I feel it should be a negative hit on performance, but surely it should be negligible.

Comment: I would have thought the time spent reading config settings whether they be machine; web or app.config to be irrelevant compared to the time it takes to actually open a database connection.

Comment: This might be a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184187/storing-connection-strings-in-machine-config-vs-storing-them-in-web-config). Please check.

Comment: @KaushalB I believe the other question is more Security related whilst this question specifically asks about performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is rather a non-question.

The machine.config always gets loaded, the app.config (or web.config) when it exists. Given both files are to be loaded, the difference is non-existent.

*If* you don't have an application configuration, the system can skip the loading of that file - but that difference will obviously be negligible.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it would be something like this. Just something I was curious about.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697(v=vs.90).aspx) it would appear that if there is anything to lose or gain performance wise it would most like gain. Although I doubt it would be noticeable.

> The configuration system first looks in the machine configuration file for the appSettings Element (General Settings Schema) and other configuration sections that a developer might define. It then looks in the application configuration file.